# How does Hand of the Apprentice work with Reach/Chain Weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, class-feature, wizard

I was looking over a Universal Wizard that I had rolled for a *Pathfinder* campaign that never lasted more than 3 sessions, and came across the Special Ability [Hand of the Apprentice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/universalist). Making a ranged attack off of my INT stat was really useful, but I never took full advantage of [Instant Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/instant-weapon), which gave me literally any weapon AND immediate proficiency with it. As such, I have two questions about how HoA works with special weapons.

1. **Do weapons with reach get extra range?**

   [image: Range Visual Aid]
2. **Do weapons on a chain continue to be swung while under the effect of HoA,
   or do they act like they are being thrown?**

   I ask this one due to the possibility that other creatures could be struck as
   the weapon flew past them.

   [image: Chain Visual Aid with Lucern Stand-in]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hand of the Apprentice is pretty specific.  It doesn't make any allowances for weapons that are long or suspended from a chain, it's one ranged attack with a melee weapon against a target within 30 feet, treated as a thrown attack but aimed with Intelligence.

The answer to both your sub-questions is **no**, unfortunately.  Unless you're using a weapon I'm not familiar with that has a quality that actually says "*When this weapon is thrown through a creature's square in order to hit a creature behind, this weapon also has a chance to hit the creature whose square it was thrown through, as if X...*" then throwing a weapon through someone's square just gives the end target soft cover against the attack, it doesn't give extra attacks.

Also, I hate to be a complete downer, but note that *instant weapon* doesn't combine well with Hand of the Apprentice.  *Instant weapon* specifies "If the weapon leaves your hand at any time, the spell ends at the beginning of your next turn."  It's missing the all-important clause "*...unless the weapon has returned to your hand.*" so if you fling the weapon once with Hand of the Apprentice it will vanish at the start of your next turn.

Comment: fair enough, I was thinking of a situation at a low level where the caster was about to loose his weapon (for instance a flying blade) and a semi-distant party member  was about to get attacked by a creature with a good chunk of its HP missing.